# How to detect key press with only single Alt modifier

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I would like to detect a keypress event only when a non-modifier key has pressed.
I then also would like to know which modifier keys have been pressed at the same time.

For Instance:
When I press Shift:_______ I would like to output nothing.
When I press Shift+A:_____ I would like to output "Shift A".
When I press Shift+Alt+A:__ I would like to output "Shift+Alt A"
When I press Alt+A:_______ I would like to output "Alt A"

However, "Alt A" does not show because without Shift/Ctrl pressed, Alt key down can't be detected with Keyboard.IsKeyDown

Following is the part of my test code.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Key key = e.Key;

    if (key.ToString().Contains("Ctrl") | key.ToString().Contains("Shift") | key.ToString().Contains("Alt"))
        return;

    Label_Test.Content = "";

    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) | Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
    {
        if (Label_Test.Content.ToString() != "")
            Label_Test.Content += "+";
        Label_Test.Content += "Shift";
    }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) | Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        if (Label_Test.Content.ToString() != "")
            Label_Test.Content += "+";
        Label_Test.Content += "Ctrl";
    }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) | Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt))
    {
        if (Label_Test.Content.ToString() != "")
            Label_Test.Content += "+";
        Label_Test.Content += "Alt";
    }
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.System))
    {
        if (Label_Test.Content.ToString() != "")
            Label_Test.Content += "+";
        Label_Test.Content += "Alt";
    }
    if (Label_Test.Content.ToString() != "")
        Label_Test.Content += " ";
    Label_Test.Content += key.ToString();
}
```

I also tried

```
if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.ToString().Contains("Alt"))
```

but the result was same.
How could I detect "Alt + A"?

EDIT: Thanks, guys for your help. I edited the last if statement which checks for Key.System like this and It just worked as I wanted.

```
if (e.Key == Key.System)
{
    key = e.SystemKey;
    if (e.SystemKey.HasFlag(Key.LeftAlt) | e.SystemKey.HasFlag(Key.RightAlt))
        return;
    Label_Test.Content = "Alt";
}
```

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern? You can bin commands to input gestures without having the trouble of this code behind stuff.

Comment: I was about to mention all you have to do to check for Alt + A (specifically A) is if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt)) && e.SystemKey == Key.A)

Comment: and mighty while this may be the case, I HAD to do this in the code behind because while clicking a button was causing the correct behavior, the mvvm xaml key bindings were causing different behavior, so I had to intercept the keys elsewhere and do something in addition when the user used the hotkey vs clicking the button. There's no way around it sometimes, especially when dealing with 3rd party components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if only modifiers pressed compare `e.Key` with all modifier keys and return empty string in this case.

If `e.Key` is not a modifier key then we need to print it along with modifiers currently pressed. To get these modifiers just iterate through all values of `ModifierKeys` enum except `None` and call `HasFlag` for each value on the `Keyboard.Modifiers`.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var modifierKeys = new[]
    {
        Key.LeftCtrl, Key.RightCtrl,
        Key.LeftAlt, Key.RightAlt,
        Key.LeftShift, Key.RightShift,
        Key.LWin, Key.RWin
    };

    var key = e.Key;
    if (key == Key.System)
        key = e.SystemKey;
    else if (key == Key.ImeProcessed)
        key = e.ImeProcessedKey;

    if (modifierKeys.Contains(key))
    {
        Label_Test.Content = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    var modifiers = Keyboard.Modifiers;
    var modifiersPressed = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ModifierKeys))
                               .OfType<ModifierKeys>()
                               .Where(k => k != ModifierKeys.None && modifiers.HasFlag(k));

    Label_Test.Content = string.Join("+", modifiersPressed.OfType<object>()
                                                          .Concat(new object[] { key }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but even with your code "Alt A" does not work. When I Hold Ctrl+Alt, Shift+Alt or Shift+Ctrl+Alt it gives me the result but Alt+A does not. It seems when I holding Alt key only, KeyEventAgrs does not give e.key the result of non-modifier keypress detection.

Comment: It gives "Alt + System" when I press Alt + any non-modifier key. When I press Alt + any key while running debug mode I hear Windows system sounds "Tin!". Perhaps non-English Windows or IME are giving this behavior? I am using US layout keyboard and just have switched to EN IME but the behavior is just the same...

Comment: @chihirobelmo I've updated code again to get right key.